# Von ... bis oder von ... auf?

Tags: preposition, standard-german

> In der Nacht vom 31. Dezember auf den 1. Januar

Können wir auch von ... bis benutzen? Gibt es einen Unterschied dazwischen oder Regeln?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Von-bis würde vielmehr verwendet um den gesamten Zeitraum vom 31. De**z**ember bis zum 1. Januar zu beschreiben. Etwa: ich habe vom 31.12. bis 1. Januar Urlaub. Hier sind beide Tage gemeint.

Bei dieser Nacht wäre von-bis zwar auch möglich wenn man sagt *"die Nacht, die vom 31.12. bis zum 1.1. dauert"*. Das ist aber ein langer Satz und klingt sehr ungewöhnlich, das verwendet man so nicht. Man kann das kürzer ausdrücken, siehe unten.
Außerdem dauert eine Nacht nicht zwei Tage. Im Satz "das Fest dauert vom 31.12. bis zum 1.1." ist das weniger seltsam, denn dieses Fest findet tatsächlich an zwei Tagen statt. Hier ist von-bis gebräuchlich.
Der Satz *"die Nacht vom 31.12. bis (zum) 1.1."* ohne den Rest (die dauert...) ist noch ungewöhnlicher.
**Also lautet die Antwort:** Hier sagt man besser "auf".

Comment: Zum Beispiel gibt es einen Satz, wie "von montag bis Freitag". Können wir auch "von montag auf freitag" benutzen?

Comment: @Max nein das geht nicht. Ohne eine Regel zu kennen, würde ich sagen das "auf" bezieht sich auf den Übergang von einem Tag **auf** den anderen. Es bezieht sich nicht auf eine allgemeine Zeitspanne. Mehrere Tage haben keinen einzelnen Übergang, auf den sich etwas beziehen kann.

Comment: "Die Temperaturen kletterten von Montag auf Freitag um 5 Grad" kann man m.E. schon sagen, in unseren Breiten aber dann selten "Montag bis Freitag", weil es kein kontinuierlicher Prozess ist, sondern nachts die Temperaturen auch immer absinken.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist interessant denn auch in diesem Satz würde ich lieber "bis" verwenden. Da sieht man dass die deutsche Sprache regional große Unterschiede zeigen kann. Sowohl was die Aussprache betrifft, als auch Satzstellung oder eben die Verwendung von Wörtern in bestimmten Situationen.

Answer (score 1):

> in der Nacht vom 31. Dezember auf den 1. Januar.
>
> von Donnerstag auf Freitag

Hier handelt es sich um **Richtungsangaben**. Man sieht das daran, dass die zweite Zeit mit Akkusativ benutzt wird, und *auf* eine der *Zwei-Wege-Präpositionen* ist, bei denen der Kasus wechselt.

Gemeint ist aber dennoch ein Ort, der Übergang auf den nächsten Tag, die tiefe Nacht. Man verwendet es auch praktisch nur so. Ausnahmen:

> von heute auf morgen
>
> von jetzt auf gleich

Hierbei handelt es sich um feste Phrasen mit der Bedeutung *plötzlich*.

Comment: Gemeint ist ein Ort? Ein Zeitraum ist doch kein Ort.

Comment: Doch.Ein Raum ist auch ein Ort. Keine Richtung.

Comment: Ein Raum ist ein Ort, außer es ist ein Zeitraum. Dass es deshalb eine Richtung sei ist eine Behauptung, die ich nicht aufgestellt habe.